# Convert string to bytes[] without changing string value in java

Tags: java

```
String str = "[B@901389";
decrypt=ssa.decryptData(str.getbytes());
```

My function is

```
public String decryptData(byte[] **encryptedstring**)
{

  ...

  ...

  return descryptedstring;

}
```

value of `encryptedstring` gets changed after passing values

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't at all clear.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the value of 'encryptedstring' changes, I assume you mean the contents of the array, not the array itself. The reason is presumably hidden in the body of the decryptData() method which you don't show. I suspect that what is confusing you is that scoping means that if you change the array itself to a different array inside the method, that change will not be reflected outside the method.  But if you change the **contents** of the array, that will affect the original.  Here's a simple example to show what I mean:

```
public class ModifyArray {

    public static void transform1(byte[] firstbytes) {
        byte[] newbytes = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' ,'6', '7', '8', '9' };
        firstbytes = newbytes;
    }

    public static void transform2(byte[] firstbytes) {
        byte[] newbytes = { 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q' ,'r', 's', 't', 'u' };
        for (int i = 0; i < firstbytes.length; i++)
            firstbytes[i] = newbytes[i];
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        byte[] mybytes = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' };
        System.out.println(new String(mybytes));

        transform1(mybytes);
        System.out.println(new String(mybytes));

        transform2(mybytes);
        System.out.println(new String(mybytes));
    }
}
```

and when run you should see this:

```
$ java -cp . ModifyArray
abcdefghij
abcdefghij
lmnopqrstu
```

transform1() modifies the array itself, and this change only exists within the scope of the method.  But transform2 modifies the contents, and this is still visible outside.  So I suspect your decryptData() method is doing the latter.